# What is the difference between using function pointers or an object when passing a function to a template?

Tags: c++

Suppose I wanted to implement `std::find_if` from `<algorithm>`. Here is one possible way I tried that works.

```
template <class In, class F>
In find_if(In b, In e, F f)
{
    while (b != e)
    {
        if (f(*b))
            return b;
        b++;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Here it seems that the user needs to know to pass an argument that returns a `bool` value. Part of my question regards if there is any way to restrict what is passed to `F f` using this technique.

Another way to implement this would involve the use of function pointers:

```
template <bool (*F)(int), class In>
In find_if(In b, In e)
{
    while (b != e)
    {
        if (F(*b))
            return b;
        b++;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Are there any differences between these two methods (other than the way they must be called; i.e the first way is called with `find_if(arg1,arg2,f)` and the second way is called with`find_if<f>(arg1,arg2)`.

If there are differences, could you please delineate and explain them to me?

Comment: It is mostly a matter of how the compiler is able to optimize the instanciated templates. Current optimizing compilers (e.g. `g++-4.8 -O2` on Linux) are clever!

Comment: One important difference is the ability of the compiler to inline the code behind the function by-address vs. a functor by-type. The latter stands a much better chance of inlining than the former (which is often impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a function pointer is more restrictive than passing a type where we apply `(*b)` on it.

In the case of the class, you may pass

- functor class (which may have state) as:

  ```
  struct HasName {
      explicit HasName(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

      template <typename T>
      bool operator () (const T& t) const { return t.get_name() == name; }

      std::string name;
  };
  ```
- or any function pointer where `f(*b)` is correct (so `f` can take float whereas `*b` is an `int`, for example).
- or lambda (C++11).